# Cannot get pins on esp 8266 adafruit wifi module to read HIGH on pin 15

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, adafruit

I have an esp8266 and I cannot get the value to read HIGH when 3.3v is applied to directly to pin by hand. I have an Arduino Uno powering the esp8266. It connects to the WiFi like it should, and now all I want is to manually see that when I apply 3v that the state will change from 0 to 1. Does anyone know how I can do this.

When I apply 3 volts directly to pin 15 it outputs 0. Even if I try digitalWrite on the pin and set it to HIGH it still says 0 and i serialPrint. My end goal if to use the arduino uno to fire and ouput on pin 8. On the arduino UNO side I am using a super sonic sensor. When the sensor is triggered I want to turn pin 8 on. From there I want to take pin 8 to feed pin 15 on the 8266 as an input. Before I did that I just wanted to see that when you manually apply 3v that the pin would read 1 or HIGH but no matter I do it wont change value. Once I get that value as HIGH I can send  a second request to the server like im already but now I want to say  that there was an intruder. Im not sure why the value wont change but being a beginner with arduino Im trying to keep it simple and ideally would like to wire it in this manner.

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "********";
const char* password = "********";

HTTPClient http;

static const uint8_t D8 = 15;
int featherPin = D8;

//int trigPin = 13;
//int echoPin = 12;
//int ledPin = 10;
//int hornPin = 11;
//
//int spaceIntruded;
//
//long duration, cm, inches;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(featherPin,INPUT);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Waiting for connection");
 }

//  Serial.begin (9600);
//  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
//  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT);
//  pinMode(hornPin, OUTPUT);
//  delay(5000);
//  Serial.println("Armed...");

}

void loop() {

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    Serial.println("yay connect");

    http.begin("http://10.150.40.121:3000/");
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");

    int httpCode = http.POST("Message from ESP8266");
    String payload = http.getString();
    Serial.println(payload);
    http.end();

    } else {
      Serial.println("Error in Wifi connection"); 
    }
//    digitalWrite(featherPin, HIGH);
    int sensorValue = digitalRead(featherPin);
    Serial.print(sensorValue);


//    if (digitalRead(featherPin) == HIGH) {
//      http.begin("http://10.150.40.121:3000/home");
//      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
//    
//      int httpCode = http.POST("Message from ESP8266");
//      String payload = http.getString();
//      Serial.println(payload);
//      Serial.print("hi");
//      http.end();
//      } else {
//        Serial.print(featherPin);
//        Serial.println("I am not hot");
//      } 


//  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
//  delayMicroseconds(1);
//  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
//  delayMicroseconds(2);
//  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
//
//  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
//  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
//
//  inches = (duration / 2) / 74;
//  Serial.println(inches);
//
//  spaceIntruded = inches;
//  
//  if (spaceIntruded <= 50 || spaceIntruded >= 900){
//      digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH);
//      digitalWrite(hornPin, HIGH); 
//      Serial.println("Intruder Detected!");
//      Serial.println("Sending text Notification...");
//      delay(500);
//      Serial.println("Armed...");
//  }
//  
//  else{
//    digitalWrite(hornPin, LOW);
//    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);
//  }
    delay(30000);

}
```

Comment: do you see how part of your code is properly formatted on gray background? .... that is because the text is indented by at least 4 spaces ....... please format the rest of the code ..... select all the code and click the `{}` icon

Comment: `when I apply 3v that the state will change from 0 to 1` what are you applying 3v to? which pin? for how long? because you have a delay of 30 seconds in each loop - so you're only checking every 30 seconds

Comment: p.s. - I didn't think the esp8266 liked such long delays

Comment: also, what output are you currently getting with your code?

Comment: Right now when I apply 3 volts directly to pin 15 it outputs 0. Even if I try digitalWrite  on the pin and set it to HIGH it still says 0 and i serialPrint. My end goal if to use the arduino uno to fire and ouput on pin 8. On the arduino UNO side I am using a super sonic sensor. When the sensor is triggered I want to turn pin 8 on. From there I want to take pin 8 to feed pin 15 on the 8266 as an input. Before I did that I just wanted to see that when you manually apply 3v that the pin would read 1 or HIGH but no matter I do it wont change value. Once I get that value as HIGH I can send a...

Comment: a second request to the server like im already doing saying that there was an intruder. Im not sure why the value wont change but being a beginner with arduino Im trying to keep it simple and ideally would like to wire it in this manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pin 15 is one of the boot configuration pins (0, 2, 15) and must be LOW at boot. To ensure it, dev boards with esp8266 have external pull-down on pin 15 (and pull-up on 0 and 2). To read the pin HIGH you must overcome the pull-down.

Adafruit Feather HUZZAH has 4.7kOhm resistor for the pull-down, so it is a 'strong' pull down. NodeMcu has 12kOhm resistor on io 15.

From schematics of Adafruit Feather HUZZAH

[image]

Note: setting pin as OUTPUT and HIGH doesn't make it read HIGH in code. Only INPUT pin state can be read with digitalRead (only on some MCUs digitalRead reads the same register set by digitalWrite).

Comment: This is unclear to me. What do you mean by overcome the pulldown? Could your break it down a little further or send me in a direction to find a resource that can clarify this. I having a hard time visualizing what you mean fully. Thanks again for taking the time to reply. I am also setting the input on line 36 as an input. I tried making forcing it HIGH to try a different idea but I know Im not fully versed with what I can and cannot do.

Comment: which esp 8266 adafruit wifi module you have exactly?

Comment: https://www.microcenter.com/product/460313/feather-huzzah-with-esp8266-wifi

Also it doesnt have to be pin 15 if the pulldown is an issue. I tried Serial printing all the pins digitalRead states from the arduino feather and i picked one that was in an off state so that it would be hot with 3.3v from the arduino when it fires the output on pin 8 when it meets the alarm triggered condition. Let me know if what Im sating is clear.

Comment: you can't determine the state of output pin with digitalRead. most of esp8266 pins are HIGH at power-up or boot

Comment: Im not trying to dertermine the state of the output pin with digital read. Im plan to fire the arduino uno on pin 8 as an output. From the that output will be hot at 5v. I take the 5 volts from the arduino board and step it down to 3.3v with a voltage regulator and two capcitors. Once I have that voltage I want to feed the output from the volatege regulator to then feed pin lets say 15 on the wifi module. Pin 15 on the wifi module would be an input. I want to determine the state of the input on the wifi module like this. I have already confirmed power all the to pin 15 and to negative

Comment: even though I read the voltage on my meter the state of the input will not change went i serial print the digital read value that is saved to a variable

Comment: I understand it but from here I can't say more that, that the input must be stronger then the pull-down. but it shouldn't be a problem, but the pull-down is strong (4.7kOhm. 10 kOhm is usual). try other pin.

Comment: Ok I understand. Im trying to understand your clue. Im not sure what you mean by pull down and 10kOHM is the usual. I just started working with arduino yesterday so I am not familiar with those terms or what I should be searching for online" I've been reading docs for several days to get it up to this point. I will try to see what I can find from what you expressed. Thanks

Comment: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/logic/pull-up-resistor.html

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/watcir.html

Comment: Thank you very much. I understand what you mean now. This is very helpful. You're saying that I theres a high resistance on the pin and that my value is not being accurately translated. I will read this material and see if I can find for getting the pin back to a true state.

Comment: So im reading something about using input_pulldown or input_pullup to change the state. Does this sound familiar to you at all? Wondering if I am on the right track.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help yesterday. It helped a lot. Got me to the next step.